# Stackmob with requires.js

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, stackmob

I'm laying out the basic structure and just started to create models. The issue is that the reference to the initialized Stackmob is lost within the model.

```
main.js
require(['modernizr','jquery','backbone', 'underscore', 'routers/router', 'stackmob'], function(Modernizr, $, Backbone, _, Router, Stackmob) {

    StackMob.init({
        appName: {appName},
        clientSubdomain: {clientSubdomain},
        apiVersion: 0
    });

    // Instantiates a new Router
    this.router = new Router();
});

Model.js
define(['jquery', 'backbone', 'stackmob', 'models/business'], function($, Backbone, Stackmob, Business) {

    var BusinessesCollection = StackMob.Collection.extend({

            model: Business,

            // Model Constructor
            initialize: function() {

            }

    });

    // Returns the Model class
    return BusinessesCollection;

});
```

How can I get the initialized StackMob object to be accessible to the model module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Introduce a *sort of instance* of StackMob?

### my-stackmob.js

```
define(['stackmob'], function(StackMob) {
    StackMob.init({
        appName: {appName},
        clientSubdomain: {clientSubdomain},
        apiVersion: 0
    });
    // return a particular StackMob that we've initialised
    return StackMob;
});
```

### main.js

(would not appear to use StackMob directly any more, based on your example code)

```
require(['modernizr','jquery','backbone', 'underscore', 'routers/router'], function(Modernizr, $, Backbone, _, Router) {
    // Instantiates a new Router
    this.router = new Router();
});
```

### Model.js

(uses my-stackmob)

```
define(['jquery', 'backbone', 'my-stackmob', 'models/business'], function($, Backbone, Stackmob, Business) {
    var BusinessesCollection = StackMob.Collection.extend({

            model: Business,

            // Model Constructor
            initialize: function() {

            }

    });

    // Returns the Model class
    return BusinessesCollection;
});
```